# Choosing a set of files by pattern matching but excluding a subset of them (bash)

Tags: bash, file

Just want to choose a subset of files:

```
 (1) DEC2017_L3S1D20.txt
 (2) FP.DEC2017_L1S1D05_2_fastqc.txt
```

So I want to choose the (1) files for downstream analysis, but excluding (2) files, the only way that i know to "choose" a pattern of files is with `*.txt` but in this way I pick up all of them.

edit: I dont want the "fastqc.txt" to be choosen, only those that ends with "L3S1D20.txt"

Comment: What is the logic or keyword to exclude the 2nd one?

Comment: I dont want the "fastq.txt" files to be chosen

Comment: `???????????????.txt`

Comment: This should do the job: `*L3S1D20.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If your `bash` version is 4.0 or above, please try something like:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in !(*fastqc).txt; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

If the `extglob` is enabled with the `shopt` builtin, you can make use of:

> !(pattern-list)
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns

Answer (score 0):

Using **grep:**

```
ls | grep -v "fastqc.txt" | grep "L3S1D20.txt$"
```